AWS Connect CCP, Angular Intercept tel: link
Using Angular
I have opened a popup window with the AWS Connect CCP using
window.open  which calls  awsapps.com/connect/ccp-v2/
How can I intercept or pass a phone number to be dialed?
I have on screen an Number
I would like this clicked and the call route through the AWS Connect Dialier popup
Thanks
